# MVC Get Vs Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-get

While going through MVC concepts, i have read that it is not a good practice to have code inside 'GET' action which changes state of server objects( DB updates etc.,).
'Caching of return data' has been given as a reason for this.

Could someone please explain this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers can cache GET requests, generally on static data, like images or scripts. But you can also allow browsers to cache GET requests to controller actions as well, using `[OutputCache]` or other similar ways, so if caching is turned on for a GET controller action, it's possible that clicking on a link leading to `/Home/Index` doesn't actually run the `Index` method on the server, but rather allows the browser to serve up the page from its own cache.

With this line of thinking, you can safely turn on caching on GET actions in which the data you're serving up doesn't change (or doesn't change often), with the knowledge that your server action won't fire every time.

POSTs won't be cached by the browser, so any POST is guaranteed to make it to the server.

Comment: One thing: `[OutputCache]` isn't client-side caching. It's server-side. Everything else makes good sense.

Comment: @StuartBranham It's actually both (by default at least). Take a look at the cache-control and related headers when you have OutputCache turned on, and you can also watch the networking tab for behavior - with OutputCache on, you'll get pages loaded from cache with no request, or 304-Not Modified results if you refresh. Without OutputCache, every request always hits the server.

Comment: One question. May be a basic one. How would MVC know if the cached data is obsolete and it should actually make a call to server to get updated data from DB?

Comment: You're talking browser, not MVC. But that's the problem with cached controller actions (or cached anything really). When the server sends the page the first time, it gives an expiration date. From the browser's perspective, it can use that cached page until then. Unless you "F5" on the browser, or attach a random query string value to the URL, the browser has no way to know that you want a fresh copy. I'd say don't turn on caching unless you know that your data won't be obsolete before the cache expires, or unless you have a strategy for appending a random query string value when you need it.

Answer (score 8):

This is by HTTP standard. The GET verb is one that should be idempotent and safe.

> 9.1.1 Safe Methods
>
> Implementors should be aware that the software represents the user in
>   their interactions over the Internet, and should be careful to allow
>   the user to be aware of any actions they might take which may have an
>   unexpected significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
>   fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important
>   distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so
>   therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Yeah, that is a better explanation in this context. Edited.

Comment: Ahh! I wish the guy didn't delete his comment. I learned something from it. Idempotent != safe, at least in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore caching for a moment. Another way of thinking about this is that search engines will store **HTTP GET** links during their indexing/crawling process, therefore they will show up in search results.

Suppose if your **/Home/Index** is implemented as **GET** but it lets say deletes a row in your Database, every time this link shows up on a search engine and somebody clicks it, you will have a delete row, and soon you have a lot deleted rows.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP spec states that GET and HEAD are expected to be idempotent, ie. they should not change server state.

One practical aspect of this, is that search robots will issue GET against any link to your site they know of. If such a GET changes user data it was not meant to change, you are in trouble.

Being idempotent has the added benefit that clients could be able to cache the result of a GET (use HTTP headers to control this).