# How to send a JSON stringified javaScript object to the server

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net and MVC 5.  I have a an object I am creating with javaScript like this:

```
        var myEdits = {
            listOfIDs: [],
            listOfValues : []
        };
```

I need to send this object to my controller and move on to the next view with the information it contains.

I can successfully stringify the object and pass it to the controller via ajax, and manipulate the data, but this does not allow me to render the new view on success.

I tried to use `window.location` and `endodeURIComponent` like this:

```
            myEdits = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myEdits));

            var postString = ("/ViewDetails/EditConfirmation/" + myEdits);

            window.location = postString;
```

But I receive this error still:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

Which I find odd, because I cannot see any :'s in the request:

> EditConfirmation/%7B"listOfIDs"%3A%5B"22"%2C"23"%2C"24"%2C"25"%2C"26"%2C"27"%2C"28"%2C"29"%2C"30"%2C"31"%2C"32"%2C"33"%2C"34"%2C"35"%2C"36"%5D%2C"listOfValues"%3A%5B""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C""%2C"Yes"%2C"Yes"%2C"Yes"%2C"Yes"%2C"No"%5D%7D

What is the proper way to pass this object via javaScript or jQuery to the controller, and have the server render the new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by placing my JSON string into a session variable with an AJAX call and then calling the action for the proper view on `success` using `window.location`.  I then retrieve the string from the session when the 'success' action is called to set up my model for the view.

Comment: I'm curious if there may be a better way to deal with this situation still, or if this method is inherently risky for some reason.

Comment: check if my answer is of any help

Answer (score 1):

It is getting URL encoded because you're using an HTTP GET. If you're sending lots of info like this, you likely want to be using an HTTP POST. See jQuery's $.ajax method.

If you really wanted to continue using a GET rest assured that if your action took in a string parameter, it will come through as expected with the colons. The `:` is getting encoded to `%3A` (see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for all of them).

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I tried decorating my controller action with `<HttpPost>`, but I come up with the same error.

Comment: @rogerdeuce since you're putting the "myEdits" as a string in the URL, it is a GET. A post requires javascript or an html form. It's probably worth reading about the difference between get and post and when to use each. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413166/mvc-get-vs-post

Comment: but then that goes back to, I can send it successfully through ajax, but I'm not able to render the new view that way.  Maybe I worded my question poorly

Comment: you can still go to a new page. in $.ajax there is a success callback, implement it and set window.location to wherever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

probably the dangerous request issue showed up because of trying to inject url path`'/ViewDetails/EditConfirmation/' + myEdits` into the browser.

**Model Class**

```
public class myEdits
{
    public List<int> listOfIds {get;set;}
    public List<string> listOfValues {get;set;}
}
```

**Javascript Part(assuming jQuery) - sending yor myEdits object**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'Home/MyMethod',
  data: myEdits,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**HomeController**

```
public void MyMethod(myEdits edits)
{
    return View("/ViewDetails/EditConfirmation/", edits);
}
```

Comment: I checked this out, the problem is that `myEdits` is created with javaScript and needs to be passed from the view, to the controller.  The controller method then needs to return a new full view.

Comment: @rogerdeuce -  so, I just updated the answer to send the data form javascript to your view. Since the model is created by giving the property names the same as your javascript object, MVC should be able to deserialize it to your model object..thank you